# Avoiding installation of certain dependency packages (texlive)

Tags: 11.10, package-management, dependencies

As Ubuntu's TeXLive is quite old (version 2009), I always hear TeX people recommending [installing the latest TeXLive directly from CTAN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17669/is-there-an-debian-ubuntu-package-containing-mdframed-sty).  (Yes, I need the same package mentioned in that question.)  I did this, and installed TeXLive 2011.

Now some packages I need to install (e.g. gummi) depend on Ubuntu's TeXLive packages. How can I prevent Ubuntu's TeXLive packages from being installed since I already have a manually installed TeXLive?

Answer (score 3):

Create a dummy package which doesn't provide any file but declares that it provides the package names from texlive. There's a tool for that: [`equivs-build`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/equivs-build.1.html) from the [equivs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/equivs) package.

`equivs-build` takes a file that declares package dependencies (such as `Provides: foo, bar` meaning that installing the package is as good as installing the packages `foo` and `bar`), and builds a `.deb` binary package. You can use [`equivs-control`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/equivs-control.1.html) to generate a template. TUG provides equivs files for [TeXlive 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2011-ex.txt) and [TeXlive 2013](http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2013-ex.txt). I'll reproduce their 2013 file here:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.4

Package: texlive-local
Version: 2013-1
Maintainer: you <you@yourdomain.example.org>
Provides: chktex, biblatex, biblatex-dw, cm-super, cm-super-minimal, context, 
 dvidvi, dvipng, feynmf, fragmaster, jadetex, lacheck, latex-beamer, 
 latex-cjk-all, latex-cjk-chinese, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp, 
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp, 
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp, latex-cjk-common, latex-cjk-japanese, 
 latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab, latex-cjk-korean, latex-cjk-thai, latexdiff, 
 latexmk, latex-sanskrit, latex-xcolor, lcdf-typetools, lmodern, luatex, 
 musixtex, passivetex, pgf, preview-latex-style, prosper, ps2eps, psutils, 
 purifyeps, t1utils, tex4ht, tex4ht-common, tex-gyre, texlive, texlive-base, 
 texlive-bibtex-extra, texlive-binaries, texlive-common, texlive-extra-utils,
 texlive-fonts-extra, texlive-fonts-extra-doc, texlive-fonts-recommended,
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc, texlive-font-utils, texlive-formats-extra,
 texlive-games, texlive-generic-extra, texlive-generic-recommended,
 texlive-humanities, texlive-humanities-doc, texlive-lang-african,
 texlive-lang-all, texlive-lang-arabic, texlive-lang-cjk, texlive-lang-cyrillic,
 texlive-lang-czechslovak, texlive-lang-english, texlive-lang-european,
 texlive-lang-french, texlive-lang-german, texlive-lang-greek, 
 texlive-lang-indic, texlive-lang-italian, texlive-lang-other, 
 texlive-lang-polish, texlive-lang-portuguese, texlive-lang-spanish,
 texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-base-doc, texlive-latex-extra, 
 texlive-latex-extra-doc, texlive-latex-recommended, 
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc, texlive-luatex, texlive-math-extra, 
 texlive-metapost, texlive-metapost-doc, texlive-music,
 texlive-omega, texlive-pictures, texlive-pictures-doc, texlive-plain-extra,
 texlive-pstricks, texlive-pstricks-doc, texlive-publishers,
 texlive-publishers-doc, texlive-science, texlive-science-doc, texlive-xetex,
 thailatex, tipa, tipa-doc, xindy, xindy-rules, xmltex 
Architecture: all
Description: My local installation of TeX Live 2013.
 A full "vanilla" TeX Live 2013
 http://tug.org/texlive/debian#vanilla
```

You may want to put your email address on the `Maintainer` line (so that you remember where this package is coming from) and tweak the list of provided packages if you didn't install a full TeXlive. Assuming you've used `debian-equivs-2013-ex.txt` as above (if not, you may need to tweak the file names), run the following commands:

```
equivs-build debian-equivs-2013-ex.txt
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2013-1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

dpkg can ignore any conflicts and dependencyes.

```
dpkg -i --ignore-depends=package1,package2 targetpackage.deb
```

But I cant see solution for apt-get for now.

Comment: From reading the man page, it seems to me that this option will only ignore packages that cannot be downloaded for some reason.  So it will still install texlive unless I unplug the network cable (or even then if some texlive packages happen to have already been downloaded but not installed).

Comment: You're right. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's a bad idea: it'll work now, but APT will choke later on dependency resolution when you install some related package or upgrade your system.

Answer (score 1):

PocketSam is correct, you cannot make apt do this; you need to mess around with dpkg directly.

You will need to manually download the gummi .deb file:

`apt-get download gummi`

Then, manually install the dependencies from gummi using apt-get, except for TeXLive.

Finally, you can use dpkg --ignore-depends to install gummi.

Beware that this is error-prone, and if you attempt to do an apt-get upgrade of gummi, it will probably pull in the old TeXLive.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package, `gummi-notex`, that does exactly that. See [here](https://launchpad.net/~gummi/+archive/gummi) for installation instructions of the ppa (currently available up to the saucy (13.10) ubuntu version)